# Change bundle id and name depending on dart-define argument

Tags: ios, flutter

The general goal is to have two copies of the application installed at the same time, but with different names.

One for the production environment, the other for the test environment.

The environment is NOT determined by the build type (`release/debug/profile`), but by the value of the `-dart-define=myEnv="production/test"` variable. And all builds making with `--release` mode in the ci/cd system and go on a *Testflight*.

If I understand correctly, this requires changing the App ID.

I have two info.plist files:

**ios/Runner/Info.plist:**

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.testcomp.testapp</string>
```

**ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist**

```
<key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
<string>com.testcomp.testapp</string>
```

and also the application identifier is specified in the file:
**ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj**
as:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.testcomp.testapp;
```

How can I change the Bundle id and Bundle name of the application based on the `--dart-define` variable?

What I have tried:

Although this script is based on the `release/debug` parameter, I still tried to add this script to the **Build phases**:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.testcomp.testapp.test" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleName testapp-beta" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleDisplayName testapp-beta" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BUNDLE_ID com.testcomp.testapp.test" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"
echo "Changed bundle id and name for Debug"
else
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.testcomp.testapp" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleName testapp" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleDisplayName testapp" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BUNDLE_ID com.testcomp.testapp" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"
echo "Changed bundle id and name for PRODUCTION"
fi
```

but the behaviour was strange:

the first attempt to build after a complete cleanup occurs without error. But the installed application has the old ID and name. The second attempt to build installs the second app with a changed ID and name and a second shortcut appears on the device, but then the Xcode crashes with the following message:
[image]

I think that this is due to the fact that the script is editing **info.plist** files, but flutter store the identifier directly into the **ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj** file, and I could not change it with the script.

I also moved this script to the very top of the **Build phases**, and also moved it to the **Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...->Build->Pre-actions**. This did not resolve the error.

But again, I need to change Bundle ID and name not depending on the build mode (--release or debug), but from the value of a `dart-define` variable.

**Flutter version: 1.22**

Comment: Did you try out this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr

Comment: @nilecrocodile did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

@nilecrocodile, to change the bundle identifier (CFBundleIdentifier) in a Flutter project using environment variables, follow these steps:

**1. Update Info.plist:**

Open any Info.plist file in your iOS project.
Replace the `<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>` value with `<string>$(BUNDLE_ID)</string>`. This references the bundle identifier specified by the **BUNDLE_ID** environment variable.

**2. Update PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER:**

In your code editor, search for occurrences of **PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER**.
Replace its value with **"$(BUNDLE_ID)"**. This ensures consistency with the bundle identifier set in the Info.plist.

**3. Create .env File:**

In your project directory, create an `.env` file to store your desired bundle identifier. For example, **BUNDLE_ID=com.example.com**.

**4. Run Flutter App with Environment Variables:**

Use the `flutter run --dart-define-from-file=.env` command to run your Flutter app, loading environment variables from the `.env` file.

**5. Verify Environment Variable:**

In your Dart code, confirm that the environment variable is loaded correctly by using `String.fromEnvironment("BUNDLE_ID")`. Print the value to ensure it matches what you provided in the .env file. Make sure to use `const` to assign `String.fromEnvironment("BUNDLE_ID")` in a variable or else it will give you an empty string.